# Why is the after pseudo element creating its own border that cannot be removed?

Tags: css

```js
const profile = document.querySelector('#profile');
let timeDelay = "";

profile.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { 
    if(this.children.length != 0) { 
        clearTimeout(timeDelay);
        return;
    }
   const onHover = document.createElement('div');
   onHover.setAttribute('id', 'miniProfile');
   this.append(onHover)
   setTimeout(()=> {
       onHover.style.top = '120%';
       onHover.style.transition = '0.5s'
       onHover.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'ease'
   }, 10)
    onHover.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { 
       clearTimeout(timeDelay)
       e.stopPropagation()
    })

})

profile.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) { 
    if(e.relatedTarget.id.toLowerCase() != this.children[0].id.toLowerCase()) {
        timeDelay = setTimeout(()=> {
            this.children[0].remove();   
        }, 500)      
    } 
})
```

```css
#profile { 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
 
#miniProfile { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 170%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #111;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url("https://media.architecturaldigest.com/photos/5da74823d599ec0008227ea8/16:9/w_2560%2Cc_limit/GettyImages-946087016.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}



#miniProfile::after { 
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height: 0;
    border:none;
    border-top: 15px solid white;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    left:0;
    width: 20px;

}

#miniProfile::before { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-top: 15px solid;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<a id="profile" href="">My Profile</a>
```

As you can see, neither the profile element, nor the miniProfile element have a border set, yet there is a light gray border over the, most likely, `after` and `pseudo` elements, but where exactly is it coming from? The pseudo elements only set `border-top`, `border-right` and `border-left`. So, where is this little gray border coming from? How do I remove it?

In case you're not seeing it, this is a snapshot from what I see on my chrome browser:
[image]

Comment: because it's not a border, it's a shadow, add **box-shadow:none !important;** to **#miniProfile** in your css

Comment: Hi could you please confirm the gray you are referring to is the triangle pointer and the gray "drop shadow"? If so, it looks like that's actually a part of the BG image you're using... You could try changing the background-position of your if you don't want the top portion of that image to be present.

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa But I want the miniProfile to have boxShadow. Are you saying the boxShadow of the miniProfile is inherited by the two after/before? Also, the boxShadow is different color. It's not gray, it's black.

Comment: @zhwatts How is that part of the image? I changed several images, and they all have this gray border. Also, changing the position does not remove that gray border.

Comment: **box-shadow: 0 0 1px #111;** in your css causes that, remove it or change it to a proper shadow that you want

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa but the box-shadow is black, whereas the tiny border is light gray. Why the difference in color?

Comment: @IloveCoffee because you gave 1px for the shadow that's why it looks like grey, give this as a shadow `box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);` and see the differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border is from the shadow, after removing the shadow, the border disappears:

```js
const profile = document.querySelector('#profile');
let timeDelay = "";

profile.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { 
    if(this.children.length != 0) { 
        clearTimeout(timeDelay);
        return;
    }
   const onHover = document.createElement('div');
   onHover.setAttribute('id', 'miniProfile');
   this.append(onHover)
   setTimeout(()=> {
       onHover.style.top = '120%';
       onHover.style.transition = '0.5s'
       onHover.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'ease'
   }, 10)
    onHover.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { 
       clearTimeout(timeDelay)
       e.stopPropagation()
    })

})

profile.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) { 
    if(e.relatedTarget.id.toLowerCase() != this.children[0].id.toLowerCase()) {
        timeDelay = setTimeout(()=> {
            this.children[0].remove();   
        }, 500)      
    } 
})
```

```css
#profile { 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:50px;
}
 
#miniProfile { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 170%;
    #box-shadow: 0 0 1px #111;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url("https://media.architecturaldigest.com/photos/5da74823d599ec0008227ea8/16:9/w_2560%2Cc_limit/GettyImages-946087016.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}



#miniProfile::after { 
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height: 0;
    border:none;
    border-top: 15px solid white;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    left:0;
    width: 20px;

}

#miniProfile::before { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 30px;
    border: none;
    border-top: 15px solid;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<a id="profile" href="">My Profile</a>
```

Comment: But why is the border gray, while the box Shadow is black? Even if I change the box Shadow to red, the small border is still gray. How come? Is there a way to remove it without removing the box shadow?